# Cannot change some camera parameters from Rpi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4, raspbian-buster

I have made an PyQt app for camera capture and changing the capture parameters on the go with a GUI. where you can use the sliders to change things like exposure, zoom etc. When I remade the same GUI with updated version of PyQt and Rpi OS changed from Buster to Bullseye 11 and updated the OpenCV version from 3.6.6 to 4.6.0 some sliders are not working.

I have a 4x.sh script file using which I pass the command to the terminal when I am moving the sliders the command is getting passed through the terminal but there is no change in the camera feed. This issue is only for **Focus, Saturation, Exposure and Gain** all other settings are working fine. the app with older pyqt and opencv while on raspbian-buster does not create the issue.   Raspberry pi 4-B. camera : Logitech c930.

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?